# Which keyboard setting corresponds to "United States (International)" in Windows XP

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm running both Ubuntu (10.04) and WinXp on the same machine, thus using the same keyboard. On Windows I have selected "United States (International)" as my keyboard setting.

In Ubuntu I have "USA International (AltGr Dead Keys)". However, they work slightly different.

When I press the <kbd>"</kbd> -key (or the <kbd>'</kbd>-key) in **Windows**, the resulting character depends on the next typed character. For example I can get foreign characters like `é` and `ë`.

When I press the <kbd>"</kbd> -key in **Ubuntu**, it just displays a `"` character, thus not allowing me to get special characters.

**I prefer the Windows version, but don't know how to get this done in Ubuntu.**

Here's a few screenshots to show you in case I failed to explain:
Windows:

[image: Windows]

Ubuntu (same key sequence):

[image: Ubuntu]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to combine the dead key with the right alt key. For example, to get `é`, type <kbd>RightAlt</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> then <kbd>E</kbd>.

I've encountered the other option in the past (possibly back in the days when I used XP) and been annoyed by it. In my view, Ubuntu's approach is superior. After all, typing `'` is more common than typing `é`; thus, it should be easier to type.

Comment: thanks, tbh I didn know what was meant by dead keys. I changed it from 'altgr dead keys' to 'with dead keys' and now has the desired effect. wóót ;). Also whether or not it's superior, depends on what language you speak. I have a US laptop but I write in dutch, french, Icelandic, ... all of which ocassionally use accents and even though type ['] is more common, going to character map everytime you are typing a text is a LOT more cumbersome. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Why would you need to go to character map with AltGr dead keys?

Answer (score 15):

If you still want the dead key behaviour (typing <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>e</kbd> resulting in `é`), you can use the **English (US, international with dead keys)** layout.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! This works great. In Xubuntu 16.04 I was even able to add the "Keyboard Layout" widget item to the panel in order to easily switch between my two keyboard layouts now: **English (US)**, and **English (US, International with dead keys)**, but one character still eludes me: how do I type the french c-cedilla with this international keyboard layout?

Comment: Weird, it's `right alt` + comma (`,`), to get `ç`. See here: http://askubuntu.com/a/363598/327339

Comment: if you ever want to know how to type a certain character, you can always consult the *keyboard layout chart* (via either the text entry panel item in the menu bar or via **system settings > text entry**, the small keyboard icon in the bottom right of the list)

The keys are shown with possible modifiers, clockwise, starting top-left: `Shift`, `Alt Gr`+`Shift`, `Alt Gr`, none.

Answer (score 7):

Use the English (US, Alternative international) layout.

Comment: This worked for me on Kubuntu 16.10.