# How to type latin small letter c with cedilla

Tags: keyboard-layout

I run Ubuntu on a DELL XPS 13 notebook that has an US keyboard configured as US international. After upgrading to version 13.10 I can no loger get a cedilla by typing <kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Instead, I get a "ć".

What should I do to get a "ç"?

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 64 bit.

Answer (score 23):

In 13.10 and above you can use right <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>,</kbd> (i.e. right Alt + comma) in English (US International with dead keys) to get <kbd>ç</kbd>. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>comma</kbd> = <kbd>Ç</kbd>

Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> + is useful for ¡¿áéúóí also.

Without using compose, on linux, it may be <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> then <kbd>C</kbd>, for cedilla `¸` plus `c` = `ç`

Comment: This works great! Braiam's answer has the full list ;)

Comment: The one that worked for me is  `RightAlt`  and then  `,` + `c` SIMULTANEOUSLY. A very hard way to write a `ç`, not practical.

Comment: What worked for me on a German keyboard is `Alt-Gr` (`Right Alt`) + `'` + `c`.

Answer (score 18):

It seems that just the step 3, proposed by Alexandre Schmidt (another answer to this same question), is enough to make the cedilla work, although the meaning of steps 1 and 2 is unknown for me at this time. I tested just this third step with success, as proposed by Jose Vitor Lopes at [Comment 42 for bug 518056](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/518056/comments/42).
For more details about this issue, check the entire log at Launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/518056).

> add one line in `/etc/environment`
>
> GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
>      QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla
>
> Restart your computer

[Source](http://josevitor.blog.br/cedilha-no-ubuntu-13-10-solucao-parcial/)

The limitation of this change is that other consonants such as "S" are still being accentuated as "Ś", instead of having an apostrophe before the letter, as on "'S", used to express contractions.

**16.04 LTS (Unity) update:** config file changes are not needed anymore. Just choose one of the following input sources for text entry: (1) English (US, international with dead keys); (2) English (US, alternative international). Cedilla (`C` + `'` = `Ç`) works fine with them.

Comment: Ça marche bien!

Comment: 14.04: It works in all software ran from Unity. But it doesn't work in Unity's search menu, and it won't work for standalone consoles (CTRL-ALT-F1...).

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 configured for English (Canada) language and unfortunately it didn't work for me. Still looking for a solution to type ç as '+c.

Comment: @Bani, see https://ubuntuforum-pt.org/index.php?topic=123209.0 for a solution on 18.04. It's in Portuguese but hopefully you'll understand if you google translate it

Answer (score 14):

**This works for Ubuntu 13.10 and might not work for newer versions:**

I was having the same issue and the following instructions solved my problem:

1. Editing the files:

**for 64 bits:**

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache
sudo gedit /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache
```

**for 32 bits:**

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache
```

changing the line

```
"cedilla" "Cedilla" "gtk20" "/usr/share/locale" "az:ca:co:fr:gv:oc:pt:sq:tr:wa"
```

to

```
"cedilla" "Cedilla" "gtk20" "/usr/share/locale" "az:ca:co:fr:gv:oc:pt:sq:tr:wa:en"
```

(note the "en" at the very end)

2. replacing "ć" to "ç" and "Ć" to "Ç" on /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose (if you use more locales, you may need to this replacement for all of them)

   sudo cp /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.bak
   sed 's/ć/ç/g' < /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose | sed 's/Ć/Ç/g' > Compose
   sudo mv Compose /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose
3. add two lines on /etc/environment

   GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
   QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla
4. restart your computer

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/518056/comments/39

Comment: I get error warning from GTK3 because of your change in (1): 
`Gtk-WARNING **: 10:36:44.682: Error parsing context info in '/usr/lib64/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache'
  "cedilla" "Cedilla" "gtk20" "/usr/share/locale" "az:ca:co:fr:gv:oc:pt:sq:tr:wa:en"`
Tried with `gtk30` instead of `gtk20`, still with the same issue.

Comment: ...and it didn't work for me.

Comment: With ubuntu 20 this works, but after a reboot, it does not work anymore, so you need manually run source /etc/enviorment, and then it starts to work again!

Comment: Yeah, the proposed solution worked for Ubuntu 13, but the im scheme changed since then. Your `GTK_IM_MODULE` variable is probably being overwritten elsewhere after /etc/environment is loaded. To confirm that, instead of adding it to /etc/environment, add it to a file in /etc/profile.d/, then try rebooting.

Answer (score 10):

There is the x11 Compose file `/usr/share/X11/locale/pt_BR.UTF-8/Compose` for Brazilian Portuguese with this contents:

```
include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"
<dead_acute> <C>    : "Ç" Ccedilla # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<dead_acute> <c>    : "ç" ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
```

So, whichever language you are using, all you need to do, to make '+c result in ç, is:

- Generate the pt_BR.UTF-8 locale, if it's not already available:

  sudo locale-gen pt_BR.UTF-8
- Add this line to your `~/.profile` file:

  export LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8

If you are a Brazilian user, and install the Portuguese language - either when installing or later from [*Language Support*](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language.html) - you can skip the just mentioned steps. Instead you can just open *Language Support* and select Brazilian Portuguese as the display language. As from Ubuntu 15.04 it's sufficient to select Brazilian Portuguese as the *Regional Formats* setting.

*Edit:*

And a third way, if you don't want to change the `LC_CTYPE` variable, is to create an `~/.XCompose` file and give it this contents:

```
<dead_acute> <C> : "Ç" Ccedilla # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
<dead_acute> <c> : "ç" ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
```

Comment: Just wanted you to know, this was the real answer for this cedilla issue. Generating the locale and changing the `.profile`. I wish I found this answer of yours before. I was almost losing my mind here, I swear! Thank you!

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me... partially. The global `export` made my Latin1 consoles go crazy. But adding the `export` only when launching GTK applications solved the thing. Thanks!!

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I get GTK errors with your new solution, probably because of the ISO file: `Gtk-WARNING **: 11:48:32.650: GTK+ supports to output one char only: "\xc7" Ccedilla # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA: <dead_acute> <C> : "\xc7" Ccedilla # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA`

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: I would rather guess that there is an issue with your locale. What does the `locale` command output?

Comment: This is the output of locale: `LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=` I need to use both locales. Somtimes I need `á`, sometimes I need `'a`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Confirmed: you cannot just write those lines in `~/.XCompose` as they are. But I copied the file `/usr/share/X11/locale/pt_BR.UTF-8/Compose` into `~/.XCompose`, leaving only the `ç` and `Ç` lines. But now the other accented stuff (á,é,...) do not work anymore outside the browsers, only ç. So this is not a solution either.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: Ok. `LANG=en_US` enables latin1 encoding, which is the reason for your problem. Ubuntu is simply designed for UTF-8, and `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` is preferred under normal conditions. If you really have reasons to enable latin1 encoding, then ... well, then you can expect to run into troubles in many situations. Anyway, good that you still figured out a way to deal with the ccedilla thing.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I will go for the `export LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8` in a script when launching browsers. Everything I've written in my life is in Latin1, so changing all that would also be a big trouble. Thanks!

Comment: This works for me! I'm on Pop Os 5.4.0! Thanks lots, @GunnarHjalmarsson

Answer (score 8):

The layout you need is the "English (International with AltGr dead keys)"

[image]

pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> brings the `ç`. <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> brings `Ç`

Comment: AltGr+, is painfull for someone used to acute+c keys.

Comment: @italo but is a real solution using the same keyboard layout until some bugs in the keyboard options gets fixed.

Comment: Where did you get this keyboard layout image?

Comment: @GabrielStaples Open the **Text entry** preferences from the system settings. Click the input source you'd like to see the keymap of, and hit the small keyboard icon in the right bottom of the list. It will show you the keymap.

Answer (score 6):

A **per user** configuration for the combination ' + c = ç can be achieved by adding:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
```

to the user's **.profile** file.

Comment: sorry for this dumb question, how do you export to user's .profile? TIA

Comment: Do "gedit ~/.profile" in the Terminal (Alt+T) and add a new line at the end of the file writing "export ...". Then save the file and reboot.

Answer (score 5):

In case a future visitor with a **German keyboard layout** winds up here, like me – even though it is outside the scope of the original question:

- **ç** is entered <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>
- **Ç** is entered <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot. That pushed me to try, and on my Swedish keyboard, same principle but with 'Alt Gr' + ','. I can get both "ç" and "Ç". I've been using workarounds for years!

Comment: I happen to be such a future German visitor. Thank you! I'm glad I found your answer before trying to fiddle with configuration files.

Comment: Same here, a German with German keyboard trying to type en français.

Comment: For me just AltGr + , works without the "c". For Ç just type SHIFT+AltGr+, - Note:AltGr is the right Alt.

Answer (score 4):

Append the line below to the file `/etc/environment` and do the login again.

> export GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla

Answer (score 3):

With Xubuntu 16.04 and generic international 105-key layout (UK English variant), I can get a cedilla on many characters by hitting `AltGr`+`=`, followed by the character I want to "decorate", i.e. `c` or `Shift`+`c`.

A similar sort of "decoration prefix" can be done with `AltGr`+X where X is `;`, `'`, or `#` for acute, circumflex, and grave respectively. And there are more, e.g. the `[` and `]` keys. These are the default characters on these keys in the UK layout -- other layouts might differ but I suspect all the relevant decorator keys are on the right-hand side of the keyboard near the `Enter` key.

Comment: That was it for me, thank you sooo much

Answer (score 2):

For latin american keyboard distribution:
<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>¿</kbd> , <kbd>c</kbd> = ç

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is still relevant after a decade, but I'm on 22.10 and a EN-UK keyboard. Being Portuguese and working in Suisse Romande, I often need the Ç or the ç. Some of the proposed solutions are a bit convoluted and seem to me harder than just googling "cedilla" and copy/pasting, or just going on the Ubuntu "Characters" app.

On my machine, in 2023, it's `AltGr` + `=`, `c` or `C`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> combination and then type `00e7` followed by <kbd>Space</kbd> which will turn into <kbd>ç</kbd> (latin small letter c with cedilla).

Another way is to use **Character Map**:

[image: Open Character Map]

[image: Character Map]

And another way and probably the best is to use a keyboard layout like Portuguese:

[image: Portuguese keyboard layout]

Comment: The Turkish layout did not work for me. I did not have this problem prior to upgrading to version 13.10, so something was changed from 13.04 to 13.10.

Comment: @user205661 How did not work for you? That's not possible. Anyway you have two more options. Did you try them?

Comment: I am looking for a strategy in which I can get a cedilla by typing two keys, as I have always done (apostrophe + c). This worked just fine in version 13.04.

Comment: I tried the Turkish layout (international, dead keys) but some of the keys are not mapped corrected. For instance, I type * and I get ).

Comment: Is there a solution along these lines? http://kuniganotas.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/how-to-use-cedilla-on-ubuntu-11-04-with-a-macbook-keyboard/

Comment: @user205661 Then try simple Turkish, not Turkish with international dead keys or something else.

Comment: The first solution (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT u 00e7 space) does not work when I am using the vim editor. In the second solution, if I understand it well, we need to copy and past the cedilla every time we use it. This is a problem, since in the Portuguese language it is used very, very often.

Comment: @user205661 Try again; it't working in vim also you have to press all 4 keys in the same time (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+U). And why don't you use Portuguese layout?

Comment: I have trıed all Turkısh layouts. Many keys do not work correctly in all of them. Anyway, when I type apostrophe + c I do not get a cedilla, but ic .

Comment: @user205661 ççç - this working great using Portuguese layout Ç

Comment: You can activate a compose keys (old way)... then it should work with compose+c+, (comma). Keep in mind that keyboard/multilanguage setup has changed a lot from 13.04 to 13.10 (unfortunately, it did work, now barely behave). Check https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1218322 , maybe you are affected by this...

Comment: A useful workaround is to add `xmodmap -e "keycode 54 = c C c C ccedilla Ccedilla"`, then you'll have the ç with right_alt+c. I don't know how to change the dead keys pairs with the New Keyboard Scheme...

Comment: @Rmano that's another bug as say in the body of the report: *(some key combos are not working as expected, that's another issue and shouldn't be mixed with this one)*

Comment: I found a solution: add the following lines to /etc/environment

GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla

Comment: This will not work without X.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Logitech K480 and my layout in NixOS + LXQt is English International + dead keys.

[image]

And I didn't found a good solution. But I found out that if I press:

---

**Solution for Logitech + NixOS + LXQt:**

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> (Alt Right) + <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) it shows a `ç`.

And <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> = `Ç`