# Cedilha (getting "ć" rather than "ç") after upgrade to 20.10

Tags: xubuntu, 20.10, input-language

I've been using Xubuntu for years now and having the "cedilha" character properly configured, so whenever I needed to use it (quite frequently) I would type **<'>** followed by  to get **"ç"**.
This had been working fine since version 16.04 when I configured it based on steps I found on this link:

[How to type latin small letter c with cedilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363115/how-to-type-latin-small-letter-c-with-cedilla)

However, I recently upgraded from version 19 to version 20.10 and now "cedilha" stopped working.

I tried to replicate the very same steps from the link above but they don't seem to work anymore.

**Please note**: *cedilha is a very common character in my native language (Portuguese) and suggestions to use screen keyboards, fancy key combinations, copy&paste, special applications to insert a cedilha in the text, assuming it's for an occasional use, are impractical and will be ignored.*

I'm looking for a way to configure cedilha the same way I would type it in previous versions: **' + c** to end up with **"ç"** (currently it produces a "ć" which is totally unacceptable).

Thanks in advance for your assistance and reply.

Comment: I'm getting the same. I could swear that a couple days ago it was working correctly but didn't take any screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

I just updated from 18 to 20.04 and had the same issue.
This worked for me:

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

include this line in the file:

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
```

save & reboot

Comment: I would suggest adding that line to `~/.profile` instead of the global `/etc/environment`. Editing `.profile` does not require `sudo`, only affects your user, and your system comes with a backup of the default version in case you make a mistake.