# Cedilla no longer working with US Intl. keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, special-characters, input-method, character-set

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with the US Intl. keyboard layout, but when I type `'`, then `c`, I'm now getting a `ć` instead of the regular `ç`. How can I fix this?

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/363115/how-to-type-latin-small-letter-c-with-cedilla?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution in another forum/website:

Append this line to the file `/etc/environment` using the command `sudo gedit /etc/environment`:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
```

Log in again. Cedilla now works as expected: `'` + `c`

Source: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=30102

Comment: I'm on 23.04 and this workaround did not worked for me.

Previously, on 18.04 I had no trouble creating cedilha with ' + c